# Allocate more than one value to an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

i'm new to Java and I'm trying to write a code that Scan for some Patients' names, also ask them to enter (y/n) if they are allergicToGluten, and then I print out a list of name of all the patients that are allergicToGluten. I just learnt Arrays but i'm still struggling in assigning many values ( name + y/n ) to an Array. I need your help.

Thank you very much :D

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: consider having an array of Objects.  These Object would be of a class that you have designed and coded.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a class that represents your patient. And then you can have array of patients

```
public class Patient{
    private String name;
    private boolean allergicToGluten;

    public Patient(String name, boolean allergicToGluten){
        this.name = name;
        this.allergicToGluten = allergicToGluten;
    }

    public boolean isAllergicToGluten(){
        return allergicToGluten;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

----

Patient[] patients = new Patient[patientCount];
```

If you don't know *patientCount* then you need [resizable-array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
ArrayList<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
// ... reading 'name' and 'isAllergic' from input
patients.add(new Patient(name, isAllergic));
```

And then you can print list of allergic patients

```
for(p : patients){
    if (p.isAllergicToGluten())
        System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to allocate more than one value to an array, but you can make an array of some class with multiple fields in it. For example,

```
public class Patient {
   public String name;
   public boolean isAllergic;
   public Patient(String name, boolean isAllergic) {
      this.name = name;
      this.isAllergic = isAllergic;
   }
}
public class Patient_Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Patient[] patients = new Patient[] {
         new Patient("Steve", true),
         new Patient("Mary", false)
      };
      for (int i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {
         if (patients[i].isAllergic) {
            System.out.println(patients[i].name);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Steve
```